# How to find a value inside more arrays based on file() function

Tags: php

Of course the title of my question will not give the idea, but i'm searching to give a style(color) for some visited links.

I have two database, little text files:

This is where i read from, and then create the links:
(db_friends.txt)

```
0982|Chiara|chiaramella|543254
7134|Paolo|pablo752|675474
9564|Andrea|andry8239|39377874
3122|Luca|luka7|26887543
4456|Riccardo|riccard904|6832787645
9721|Fabio|fab78|38307696
3284|Francesco|frafra54|9325454
9555|Luigi|lulu14|0055468
1485|Matteo|matty990|897103464
0986|Laura|lau3245|324891000
3714|Claudio|cla235|36464820
9986|Giovanni|giojo982|0005405
8244|Stefano|stefy734|45367
7731|Marco|markkkk998|355647689
2123|Roberto|robn88|809678741
```

This second, is where i save the value id of the link when i clicked on:
(visited.txt)

```
9564
3284
3714
8244
```

Now i echo the list of friends with this foreach loop:

```
<?php
$db_friends = file("db_friends.txt");
$db_visited = file("visited.txt");

foreach($db_friends as $key => $profile) {
    list($uni_id, $name, $nick, $num_id) = explode("|", $profile);
    if (in_array($uni_id, $db_visited)) {
        $style = "style=\"color: red;\"";
    } else {
        $style = "";
    }
    ?>
    <div id="fr_slot">
        <a <?= $style; ?> href="./?alpha_id=<?= $nick; ?>&id=<?= $key ?>" target="_tab"><?= $name ?></a>
    </div>

<?php } ?>
```

The result should be to get a different color (red for example) to the matched id inside visited.txt.
In this case, let say that Andrea, Francesco, Claudio and Stefano, should have a red color, but i'm not be able to get what i'm trying to do.
Hope in your help! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you considered actually using a database? ``SELECT `friends`.*, `visited`.`id` IS NOT NULL AS `visited` FROM `friends` LEFT JOIN `visited` USING (`id`)`` - so much easier!

Comment: Probably need to use `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` with `file()` or `trim()` the value from visited.txt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) ***flags***

```
FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES
```

Change code like below:-

```
$db_friends = file("db_friends.txt",FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$db_visited = file("visited.txt",FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

Note:- it will automatically take care of new line/empty line issues in your code.Nothing to do extra.

Answer (score 2):

It's not working because entries in `file` still have the trailing newline at the end of each one. You will need to `trim`, which you can do with ease:

```
$db_visited = array_map('trim',$db_visited);
```

You should probably also do that with `$db_friends`, because your `$num_id` has a newline too and it may cause issues later.

But please do seriously consider using an actual database such as MySQL, you'll find your life becomes so much easier.

Comment: I would disagree on the database recommendation though, I think it all depends on your application size and intention anyway. Launching a MySQL might be too much, and if the file approach works then that's good enough. If a database is desired anyway, SQLite might also an appropriate recommendation.

Comment: @sidyll True, I may have gotten used to MySQL as a "default thing to have", but InnoDB in particular really got me hooked :D